# encoding '+' character on a NSURLRequest

Tags: ios, objective-c, character-encoding, url-encoding

I am loading a webView with an external url and post data.

Everything works fine, unless the data contains the '+' character, then it fails.
I've tried to encode the data in differents ways but I can't make it work. 
How can I correctly encode the plus character?

```
-(void) cargarWebViewTPVRedys:(TPVRedsys*) redsys{

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://sis-t.redsys.es:25443/sis/realizarPago"]; // PRUEBAS
    // NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"https://sis.redsys.es/sis/realizarPago"];     // REAL
    NSString *body = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"DS_SIGNATURE=%@&DS_MERCHANTPARAMETERS=%@&DS_SIGNATUREVERSION=%@",redsys.Ds_Signature,redsys.Ds_MerchantParameters,redsys.Ds_SignatureVersion];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc]initWithURL: url];
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    //[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding]];
    //[request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody: [body dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding allowLossyConversion:false]];
    NSLog(redsys.Ds_Signature);
    NSLog(redsys.Ds_MerchantParameters);
    NSLog(redsys.Ds_SignatureVersion);

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
}
```

Comment: Can not you use stringbyreplacingoccurrencesofstring?

Comment: The '+' character must arrive at the url, so I cant just remove it

Comment: Where is the "+" sign, it is not in the question.

Comment: in redsys.Ds_Signature ( is a NSString),

Comment: Hi D4rWiNS! Is TPVRedsys a class you have developed? or have you downloaded it from some page? I have to use TPV with an iOS app and I'm struggling looking for a redsys library for Objective C.

Comment: I developed it myselft

Comment: I've asked about my problems making ios payments through Redsys API here in SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44936947/ios-3des-enccryption-for-tpv-payments could you please see what's the problem with my code?

Comment: I generate the signature on the server side so I don't know where is your problem at the IOS code, but seems like the problem is in the ds_signature

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that replace the '+' character for Its hexadecimal value

```
NSString *body = [body2 stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@"%2B"];
```